# MySQL Workbench to generate Catalog diff

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have problem using generate catalog diff in database tab, in MySQL Workbench, I am using ver5.2.33, the option generate catalog option has been disabled, while other option like, forward eng, reverse eng, synchronize model, works fine. Still I used the existing model only.

Option generate catalog diff is always been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 5.2.35 CE which should be similar to yours

- Make sure all tabs are closed. ( For simplicity and lack of confusion )
- Now that you are on "home" which should be an icon of a house on the tab, Go ahead and select new EER Diagram
- On this page, you are going to click on menu Database and then select "Create diff Catalog"
- Here you will choose option live for both connections
- The next screen you will select your live database
- Then on the next screen you will select the database you wish to compare.
- The next screen you will select your live database you wish to compare to
- Then on the next screen you will select the database you wish to compare.
- The next screen will show you all your differences, it may take a little while for them to appear. For me, it took about 30 seconds with a 25MB database

If you already know those steps and cannot seem to reach them, then I highly suggest reinstalling your MySQL Workbench software.